# stretch categories and xbars in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

How can I stretch the categories and xbars vertically? There should be more space between the different xbars.

My file `datatable.txt`:

```
one two three
A   2   0.3
B   3   0.4
C   4   0.5
D   5   0.6
E   4   0.7
F   3   0.6
G   2   0.5
H   3   0.4
I   4   0.3
J   5   0.4
K   4   0.5
L   3   0.6
M   2   0.7
N   3   0.6
```

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    xmin=1,
    xmax=6,
    ytick=data,
    yticklabels from table={datatable.txt}{one}
]
\addplot plot [error bars/.cd, x dir = both, x explicit] table [x=two, y expr=\coordindex, x error = three] {datatable.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{xbars and standard deviations}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve more space between bars by:

1. Increasing the height of the plot: e.g. change `height=10cm` to `height = 15cm`;
2. Keeping the same height, but making the bars narrower e.g. change `bar width=10pt` (the default) to `bar width=7.5pt`; or
3. You can combine a height and bar width adjustment.

Here is a tall plot with more spacing between the categories, with `height=15cm` and `xbar={7.5pt}`

[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[header=true]{
    one two three
    A   2   0.3
    B   3   0.4
    C   4   0.5
    D   5   0.6
    E   4   0.7
    F   3   0.6
    G   2   0.5
    H   3   0.4
    I   4   0.3
    J   5   0.4
    K   4   0.5
    L   3   0.6
    M   2   0.7
    N   3   0.6
}\data

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, width=10cm, height=15cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    bar width={7.5pt},
    xmin=1,
    xmax=6,
    symbolic y coords={N,M,L,K,J,I,H,G,F,E,D,C,B,A},
    ytick=data,
    ytick style={draw=none}
]
\addplot [
   error bars/.cd,
   x dir = both,
   x explicit,
   ] table [
   x=two,
   y=one, 
   x error = three
   ] {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{xbars and standard deviations}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```